# how to check the value of field for a particular ID in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I am making leave planner, where I want a condition to be checked before the sharepoint hits the workflow.

I want that `if [Number of Days]+[Availed]<=10`, then the leave approval process starts, else not.

`[Number of Days]` is a column that calculates the number of days requested in a particular request, and
`[Availed]` is a column that gets updated with the total number of leaves approved.

So basically, every time a request is approved, the number of days will get added to previously availed days.

I tried using the `[Number of Days]+[Availed]<=10`, in list validation settings. But did not work because every time it is working on the current request. Rather I want it to fetch the `[Availed]` on previous ID's Availed and `[Number of Days]` of current request.

Lets say, in the last request I availed 2 leaves, and this time I request for 5 number of days leaves, then this formula should calculate as `2+5<=10`, else it should prompt for an error.

Is there are way I can apply this check? I tried using SD workflow, but it became more tedious.

[image: Screenshot]
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I wonder what is going wrong. I have applied list validation setting as [Number of Days]+[Availed]<=10, my workflow is unable to update the value of Availed and Leave Balance.

Comment: If I remove this, then workflow is working as expected but then list validation is not available, which is mandatory requirement. I am attaching the image of my workflow.